# Want my tags to get approved by admin Using acts_as_taggable_gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I want my tags to first get approved by user with the role of admin ,before it gets displayed to general users(which in my case are user with role doctor and patient) using acts_as_taggable gem in  rails.
How to do it ?(Was thinking of  setting tags owner as admin when  submitted by user(with role doctor or patient) making its owner admin and in admin panel show all the tags with owner admin and on approval it change its owner to general )
But don't know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an 'approved' attribute on tags and only display approved tags. You'll have to create a tag model that inherits from acts_as_taggable's tag model in which you can define an approved scope for use in controllers and views.

```
rails g migration add_approved_to_tags approved:boolean
```

create a tag.rb file in the models folder

```
class Tag < ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
  def self.approved
    where(approved: true)
  end
end
```

In your controller

```
@tags = Tag.approved
```